# Issue with job submission from Flink Job UI (Exception:org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment$ProgramAbortException)

Tags: apache-flink

I have simple java code for flink job

```
List<Tuple2> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i  = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     list.add(new Tuple2(Integer.valueOf(i), "test" + i));
}
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.fromCollection(list).print();
env.execute("job1");
```

I packaged this code and create a jar: say flink-processor-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, upload it to JobManager from Submit job UI. No issues in upload. I see the EntryClass has the main class (com.abc.xyz.streaming.FlinkProcessor)
Now, i submit the job from "Submit Job Ui "with some params (--ns.conf1 abc.file --ns.conf2 xyz.file) and specified the main class (com.abc.xyz.streaming.FlinkProcessor). 
**The job submission fails.** In the JobManager, i see the following errors.

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment$ProgramAbortException
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamPlanEnvironment.execute(StreamPlanEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamPlanEnvironment.execute(StreamPlanEnvironment.java:53)
    at com.abc.xyz.streaming.FlinkProcessor.run(FlinkProcessor.java:114)
    at com.abc.xyz.streaming.FlinkProcessor.main(FlinkProcessor.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessor
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getOptimizedPlan(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.utils.JarHandlerUtils$JarHandlerContext.toJobGraph(JarHandlerUtils.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$getJobGraphAsync$6(JarRunHandler.java:142)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-06-16 16:14:20,588 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler    - Unhandled exception.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program plan could not be fetched - the program aborted pre-maturely.

System.err: Running flink job :2020-06-16T23:14:20.476Z
 Error msg: org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment$ProgramAbortException
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamPlanEnvironment.execute(StreamPlanEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamPlanEnvironment.execute(StreamPlanEnvironment.java:53)
```

**When i submit the same job using flink run command, it works fine. No errors.**

*flink run -c com.abc.xyz.streaming.FlinkProcessor /Users/abc/target/flink-processor-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --ns.conf1 abc.file --ns.conf2 xyz.file*

Not sure what I am missing here? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. 
I was wrapping my code with

```
try { 
 List<Tuple2> list = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i  = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     list.add(new Tuple2(Integer.valueOf(i), "test" + i));
 }
 StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
 env.fromCollection(list).print();
 env.execute("job1");
} catch (Throwable t) { 
ignore t
};
```

changed the exception block
 **try { ..... } catch (Exception exp) { ignore exp};**
After this, it started working.

Thanks !